# How to merge data.tables keeping a column pair mapping fixed?

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have two `data.table`

```
>a <- data.table(code=c('FI', 'NO', 'SW'), name=c('Finland', 'Norway', 'Sweden'), category=c('A', 'B', 'C'), val_1=c(1,2,3))

>a
   code    name category val_1
1:   FI Finland        A     1
2:   NO  Norway        B     2
3:   SW  Sweden        C     3

> b <- data.table(code=c('FI', 'NO', 'FI'), category=c('A', 'B', 'C'), val_2=c(4,5,6))
> b
   code category val_2
1:   FI        A     4
2:   NO        B     5
3:   FI        C     6
```

If I `merge` these `data.tables` I get the expected output

```
> merge(a, b, all=T, by=c('code', 'category'))
   code category    name val_1 val_2
1:   FI        A Finland     1     4
2:   FI        C      NA    NA     6
3:   NO        B  Norway     2     5
4:   SW        C  Sweden     3    NA
```

However, the output I am looking for is

```
   code category    name val_1 val_2
1:   FI        A Finland     1     4
2:   FI        C Finland    NA     6
3:   NO        B  Norway     2     5
4:   SW        C  Sweden     3    NA
```

where the country name is taken from `a`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just spin off the code-to-name mapping and add it back in when needed.

```
codemap <- a[,name,keyby=code]
a[,name:=NULL]

m <- merge(a,b,all=TRUE,by=c('code','category'))
#    code category val_1 val_2
# 1:   FI        A     1     4
# 2:   FI        C    NA     6
# 3:   NO        B     2     5
# 4:   SW        C     3    NA

setkey(m,NULL)
codemap[m]
#    code    name category val_1 val_2
# 1:   FI Finland        A     1     4
# 2:   FI Finland        C    NA     6
# 3:   NO  Norway        B     2     5
# 4:   SW  Sweden        C     3    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
 merge(a, b, all=TRUE, by=c('code', 'category'))[,
              name := name[!is.na(name)][1L], code]
 #    code category    name val_1 val_2
 #1:   FI        A Finland     1     4
 #2:   FI        C Finland    NA     6
 #3:   NO        B  Norway     2     5
 #4:   SW        C  Sweden     3    NA
```

Comment: Thanks. I am a newbee in R, what is the meaning of [1L]?

Comment: @imsc It is just to coerce to `integer` class.  But you can use `[1]`.  Usually, the integer will be a bit more fast for big datasets.

Comment: I am still missing something. How is it different from `[,name := name[!is.na(name)], code]`.

Comment: @imsc I thought if there are multiple (duplicate) elements for each 'code', select the 1st one.  You are right, that for this case even without `1` should also work.